# Mips assembly, .data section

Tags: assembly, mips

I want to get the address of the global value declared at .data. la instruction is not recognized? How else to perform that

```
.data
word1:  .word 0
word2:  .word 0
.text
    .globl __start
    __start:
    la $v0,word1 --> here I receive a syntax error.
```

I want to store byte in word1, and another byte in word2

I can't obtain the address

Comment: What assembler are use using ? It works fine when assembling on MARS

Comment: You should be able to use `li`. Or a combination of `lui` and `ori`.

Comment: Please give the toolchain/platform you are using, along with the error message. Your code looks ok, but syntax varies slightly from setup to setup. (For example referring to registers as $v0 vs. v0).

Answer (score 1):

`la` is not a real MIPS instruction, it is a convenient assembler macro.  It is usually broken down into `lui` and `ori` or `addi`.  On systems where the linkage is more complicated than a flat layout known at static linking time, your assembler may be unable to implement it.  To access your data segment you may need to dereference a global pointer (GP) or do an indirect load.